# Find tables with specific criteria - Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

How to find tables in a schema that start with *NUM_* whose data is more than 0 records.

Eg:
Consider I'm a couple of schemas

1. Schema1
2. Schema2
3. Schema3

*Schema1 has tables*:

- NUM_table11 (has 0 records)
- NUM_table12 (has 20 records)
- DummyTable1 (has 10 records)

*Schema2 has tables*:

- NUM_table21 (has 0 records)
- NUM_table22 (has 20 records)
- DummyTable2 (has 10 records)

*Schema3 has tables*:

- NUM_table31 (has 0 records)
- NUM_table32 (has 20 records)
- DummyTable3 (has 10 records)

I want to get only Schema2 tables, whose name starts with *NUM_* and has more than 0 records.
i.e, in this case **NUM_table22**

Can anyone help on achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables (and don't feel like creating ones either), so I'll show it on another example - looking for the `EMP` tables throughout my database.

Connect as a privileged user, the one that has access to `DBA_TABLES` (as you want to search *all* users, right?). One of those is `SYS`, if you don't have any other.

Then write a PL/SQL block which looks into the `DBA_TABLES`, searches for tables whose name begins with `EMP`. Dynamic SQL (i.e. `execute immediate`) counts rows in those tables and - if it is a positive number - returns that table as an output.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select owner, table_name
  5                  from dba_tables
  6                  where table_name like 'EMP%'
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.owner ||'.'||
 10                         cur_r.table_name into l_cnt;
 11      if l_cnt > 0 then
 12         dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.owner ||'.'|| cur_r.table_name ||' = ' || l_cnt);
 13      end if;
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
HR.EMPLOYEES = 107
SCOTT.EMP = 14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

In my databases, there are two such tables:

- one is owned by `HR`, its name is `EMPLOYEES` and contains 107 rows
- another one is owned by `SCOTT`, its name is `EMP` and contains 14 rows

I believe that you shouldn't have any problems in adjusting that code to your needs.

I'm not sure why would you want to search only through `schema2`; in that case, it is simpler to connect as `schema2` and do the same job using `user_tables` (or `all_tables`) (so you don't have to connect as a privileged user).

Or, if you want to pick the user within that code, you'd add yet another condition into the `where` clause (line #6):

```
and owner = 'SCHEMA2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Littlefoot's answer would work but may take longer. Assuming stats has been collected the following SQL should give you want you want and much faster. If stats are not fresh then it can give wrong result.

`select * from DBA_TABLES where TABLE_NAME like 'NUM_%' and NUM_ROWS > 0`